# Function argument inheriting two types simultaneously

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a constructor in C++ (C++17 is fine), which has one argument, and I want this argument to be inherited from two types.

So I have this struct:

```
struct SceneNodeData {
    Drawable* drawable;
    Transformable* transformable;

    SceneNodeData(
        Drawable* drawable,
        Transformable* transformable
    ) : drawable(drawable), transformable(transformable) {}
};
```

But for convenience I want another constructor, with only one parameter, which is `Drawable` and `Transformable` at the same time (like `Sprite`):

```
struct SceneNodeData {
    Drawable* drawable;
    Transformable* transformable;

    SceneNodeData(
        <Drawable, Transformable>* drawableAndTransformable
    ) : drawable(drawableAndTransformable), transformable(drawableAndTransformable) {}
};
```

Is there any way to do this in C++ ?

Comment: What is the type that could be passed to this constructor, and how is this type defined?

Comment: Make it a template and restrict it with `std::enable_if` and `std::is_base_of`.

Comment: @dbush examples are: 
```class Sprite : public Drawable, public Transformable``` or ```class Text : public Drawable, public Transformable``` (but it can be anything which is derived from Drawable and Transformable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a template and constarin the type using the type trait [`std::is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) to check if the type provided can be cast to both types.  That would look like

```
struct SceneNodeData {
    Drawable* drawable;
    Transformable* transformable;

    template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T*, Drawable*> &&
                                          std::is_convertible_v<T*, Transformable*>, bool> = true>
    SceneNodeData(T* drawableAndTransformable) : drawable(drawableAndTransformable), transformable(drawableAndTransformable) {}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Not quite, but:

- You could define a class `DrawableTransformable` publicly derived from both `Drawable` and `Transformable`, and have your constructor take an argument of type `DrawableTransformable*`. Any concrete class derived from `DrawableTransformable` would need to implement the pure virtual functions from both `Drawable` and `Transformable`.
- You could define a constructor template taking `T*` with an SFINAE check that `T` is publicly derived from both `Drawable` and `Transformable`. Or you could omit the SFINAE check and simply let a hard error occur in the initialization of `drawable` and `transformable`.